# why does i18n dont work with recent json files

Tags: node.js, next.js, internationalization, nodes, i18next

I have a Header component imported in the SiteLayout component, which is used on every page of my website. I want to use i18n for translations, and it works successfully on all pages except for the Header. The translations work on previously created pages, but not on the most recent ones, and I can't understand why!

```
import {useTranslation} from 'next-i18next';
const Header = () => {
        const {t} = useTranslation('headerfooter');
        <...>
return (
        <p> {t('test')} </p>
<...>
)
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
    return {
        props: {
            ...await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['headerfooter']),
        },
        revalidate: 60,
    };
}
```

not work but

```
import {useTranslation} from 'next-i18next';
const Header = () => {
        const {t} = useTranslation('forms');
        <...>
return (
        <p> {t('test')} </p>
<...>
)
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
    return {
        props: {
            ...await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['forms']),
        },
        revalidate: 60,
    };
}
```

will work, no changes between this two json files exept name and header footer was created after forms

Debug says that my file is charged.. :
`i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace headerfooter for language fr {`

Answer (score 0):

i find...
you must add this function without specify the namespaces in the pages using your components and your parents components

```
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
    return {
        props: {
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale)),
        },
        revalidate: 60,
    }
}
```